# How many ways are possible to place k items in n spots such that order of k items is not disturbed

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

I have k items, need to place them in n spots(n>k). In how many ways can this be done?

Example - 
for k=2 and n=4,
 these are the possibilities assuming items to be like this [1,2]
12--
1-2-
1--2
-12-
-1-2
--12

I am unable to find a general solution. Please help. This is not a homework/assignment; I am stuck as this is a sub-part of a programming problem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this works out as $\binom nk=\frac {n!}{k!(n-k)!}$

Comment: Thanks a lot! I need to think a lot more before giving up so early

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have $(n-k)$ empty spaces you need to place between, before, or after the $k$ items.

So, how many ways can you place $(n-k)$ spaces in $(k+1)$ bins.  Which is $$(k+1)+(n-k)-1\choose {(n-k)}$$
In your example:
$${(2+1)+(4-2)-1\choose {(4-2)}}={4\choose 2}=6$$
ETA: which simplifies to$${n\choose{n-k}}={n\choose k}$$
as abiessu commented above.